# How to find the CDF in the following formula?

Tags: probability-distributions, change-of-variable

I need your help with the following formula. If we have:

\begin{equation}
\gamma=\frac{E_s}{N_0} Y^2 
 \end{equation}

And:

\begin{equation}
\bar{\gamma}=\frac{E_s}{N_0}\prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i
 \end{equation}

How did they come up with the following expression:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_\gamma (\gamma )= {F_Y}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\gamma \prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i}{\bar{\gamma}} }\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Where $F$ is the CDF.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a problem to compute BER or SER and you need to give more context and maybe post to SP Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather straight forward:
$$\frac{\gamma}{\bar \gamma} = \frac{Y^2}{\prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i} \Rightarrow Y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{\gamma\prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i}{\bar \gamma}}$$
if we further assume $Y \ge 0$ then we have $Y = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma\prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i}{\bar \gamma}}$.

Now $F_\gamma (x) = \text{Pr}(\gamma \le x)$ and $F_Y (y) = \text{Pr}(Y \le y)$.

So if $\gamma \le x \Rightarrow Y = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma\prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i}{\bar \gamma}} \le  \sqrt{\frac{x\prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i}{\bar \gamma}} \Rightarrow F_\gamma (x )= {F_Y}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x \prod_{i=1}^N \Omega_i}{\bar{\gamma}} }\right)$

I considered $Y \ge 0$ because i think $E_s$ = symbol Energy and $N_0 = $ noise variance.